# Why user password look different in debug mode and insert to sql

Tags: freeradius

How can I change the %USER-Password value like when I look in the debug mode Access-Request?

debug mode like this:
"User-Password = "2ixxigux+""

when insert to the sql like this:

"[sql]   expand: %{User-Password} -> 2ixxigux=2B"

Thanks

Comment: Marking as unclear because as someone quite familiar with freeradius, I don't understand what's being asked.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL module only allows a limited character set for value substitutions in SQL queries.  FreeRADIUS v4.0.x (unreleased as of 13/09/17) is slightly better in this regard, in that if the SQL library provides an escape function, then that function is called instead.

The reason why the values are different in this case, is because '+' is not in the default safe characters list as so is escaped (with the format `=<hex><hex>`).

You can change the allowable characters with the `safe_characters` config item in `raddb/mods-available/sql` see [here](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v4.0.x/raddb/mods-available/sql). Be careful not to allow characters which could be used in SQL injection attacks.